# Google chrome or chromium error

Tags: 15.10, google-chrome, chromium, vnc

Installing google chrome or chromium on ubuntu 15.10 VPS (OpenVZ, VNC) but getting below error.

```
# google-chrome & 
/usr/bin/google-chrome: line 64: /dev/fd/62: No such file or directory /usr/bin/google-chrome: line 65: /dev/fd/62: No such
file or directory Failed to move to new namespace: PID namespaces
supported, Network namespace supported, but failed: errno = Operation
not permitted
```

if anyone know a solution please help me.

Comment: I think there is no file in /dev/fd directory. It may be google-chrome errors. Try this command :
    `ln -s /proc/self/fd /dev/fd`

Comment: ln: failed to create symbolic link '/dev/fd/fd': No such file or directory @NgocThangPham

Comment: Can you post `ls /dev/fd` output?

Comment: root@localhostub:~# ls /dev/fd
0  1  2  3             @NgocThangPham

Comment: check if you installed `udev`. You can use `man udev` if manpage hasn't been showed so let install `udev`. If not, you should install udev with: `apt-get install udev`

Comment: udev is already the newest version. @NgocThangPham

Comment: please post `ls /proc/self/fd` output

Comment: root@localhostub:~# ls /proc/self/fd
0  1  2  3

Comment: root@localhostub:~# ls /proc/self/fd
0  1  2  3
@NgocThangPham